# Renaming files in lexicographical order with a numerical pattern that increases sequentially with fixed padding

Tags: zsh, filenames, rename

I have files such as

```
a
bb
ccc
abc
emrls
```

I would like to rename them so that, after sorting them (for example, lexicographically), each file gets the following name:

```
00001
00002
00003
etc
```

where the # of digits for the 0 padding is specified a priori, e.g. 6 in the case above (assuming that we know how many digits are needed).

Since the shell I am most comfortable with is `zsh`, I'm interested in solutions that benefit from features on `zsh` (maybe using `zsh`'s `zmv`?). I would also be interested in solutions that are compatible with Bash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `l` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) to pad a number on the left.

```
i=0; for x in *; do ((++i)); mv -- $x new/${(l:6::0:)i}; done
```

There is a relatively simple way to do this with only POSIX features: start numbering at 1000001 (for 6 digits) instead of 1, and strip off the leading `1`. It is less straightforward but a few characters shorter.

```
i=1000000; for x in *; do i=$((i+1)); mv -- "$x" new/${i#1}; done
```

If you want to take advantage of `zmv`, you can use an arithmetic expression that increments `i` inside the replacement text.

```
i=0; zmv '*' '${(l:6::0:)$((++i))}'
i=1000000; zmv '*' '${$((++i))#1}'
```

Add the `o` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) if you need to sort the files in a different order. With `zmv`, you need to pass the `-Q` flag when the pattern contains glob qualifiers.

Comment: Wow.. @Gilles, this is better! :-)

Comment: Thanks Gilles, this is great. By the way, what is the purpose of `--`  in `mv`?

Comment: @intrpc The `--` is in case one of the file names begins with `-`. It tells `mv` that what follows is not an option.

Comment: This seems to work: `i=0; zmv '*' '$((++i))` but I am getting an error with `i=0; zmv '*' '${(l:6::0:)$((++i))}'` (the first of the two options suggested for `zsh`). I

Comment: Ops. I think it is because I typed the letter `l` as the number `1` (I didn't copy+paste). It's working again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this bash snippet.

```
[centos@centos new]$ touch a bb ccc dddd eee f gh i
[centos@centos new]$ touch abc emrls cdg sf
[centos@centos new]$ touch ABC A BB CCC DD GI KLM kmna kabc mas nas san fin zoo
[centos@centos new]$ \ls -1
a
A
abc
ABC
bb
BB
ccc
CCC
cdg
DD
dddd
eee
emrls
f
fin
gh
GI
i
kabc
KLM
kmna
mas
nas
san
sf
zoo
[centos@centos new]$ a=0; for i in *; do a=$(($a+1));  b=`printf "%06d" $a`; mv -v ${i} ${b};  done
`a' -> `000001'
`A' -> `000002'
`abc' -> `000003'
`ABC' -> `000004'
`bb' -> `000005'
`BB' -> `000006'
`ccc' -> `000007'
`CCC' -> `000008'
`cdg' -> `000009'
`DD' -> `000010'
`dddd' -> `000011'
`eee' -> `000012'
`emrls' -> `000013'
`f' -> `000014'
`fin' -> `000015'
`gh' -> `000016'
`GI' -> `000017'
`i' -> `000018'
`kabc' -> `000019'
`KLM' -> `000020'
`kmna' -> `000021'
`mas' -> `000022'
`nas' -> `000023'
`san' -> `000024'
`sf' -> `000025'
`zoo' -> `000026'
[centos@centos new]$
```

Comment: I am assuming ls -1| sort would do your lexicographical sort, however if you need any other type of sort, just change that command but the zero padding and moving can be same.

Comment: Ugh, [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)! `$(ls -1 | sort)` is the same thing as `$(ls)` anyway, and your code fails with file names containing whitespace or globbing characters (you'd need to `set -f` and set `IFS` to a newline, and then your code would still fail with filenames containing nonprintable characters or newlines). `for i in *; do` …

Comment: Done. Just updated the snippet. Thanks @Gilles